# implement a listener/method in angular 2 which gets called on every page request

Tags: angular, listener

I am trying to implement a listener/method which gets called every time new request comes.

Comment: This question provides so little information that it's hard to know whether this is a question at all. Please provide more information. Add the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried, and where you failed.

Comment: I think I know what you want but I'm gonna put as many efforts in my response than you did in your answer : `ng2-interceptors`. Hint, it's from my `package.json`.